# Login to Wordpress from another website

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I have a Simple PHP Website at `www.example.com` and I have a wordpress blog at `www.example.com/blog/` and both of them have user login pages. I would like the user to logged into the wordpress blog as well when the user logs in using `www.example.com` login.

Please help

Comment: wordpress sets some cookies when the user logs in, then it checks for the cookies to see if the current user is logged in or not http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/pluggable.php line 663 to see exactly what is happening.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can store sessions and cookies across the same Domain, as example, if you have example.com with a login, example.com/blog or blog.example.com the tricks works too it depends only on the "way you set it up"

Comment: will check it out and let you know :) thankx

Comment: whoaa.. there are lotta things in there, and am not an expert WP coder. I know its like asking a bit more, but could you point me out what cookie excactly i need to set ?

Comment: I found some code like this `require('wp-blog-header.php');
$user_login = 'admin';
$user = get_userdatabylogin($user_login);
$user_id = $user->ID;
wp_set_current_user($user_id, $user_login);
wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
do_action('wp_login', $user_login);` but this seems to be taking me to the login page

Answer (score 3):

The proper way of doing it is

- Create a wordpress plugin
- Use the plugin to listen for the wordpress engine initiation
- On initiation check for the user session in the browser or in your external application
- If a user session is found (assuming your usernames and emails are unique for both systems, so that a single registration is allowed with it) check for a wordpress user with matching username or email
- If a wpuser is found, set the current user as that
- If no user is found create a new wordpress user and set him as the current user

There are neat API's available for doing this in wordpress. We have used it to [integrate wordpress](http://www.webgalli.com/blog/elgg-wordpress-integration/) with many external websites, CMS and Social networking sites like Elgg.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [bbPress Integration](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bbpress-integration/) plugin that does the same thing to integrate WordPress and BBPress forums.

Basically you will simply need to create some cookies on the user browser crypted with the appropriate secret keys.

Comment: Hi Vincent o you have any explantion for this Im interested too and Im using bbpress in my site.I created a popup login for wordpress but from site2 I want to login to site 1 how is possible please if you can guide would be very helpfull.